# Assign role to user at each login of a FormAuthentication login page in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, roles

I'm having trouble understanding how the Role mechanism works with ASP.NET.

I have a Microsoft SQL Server database where everything is already set up and I don't want to add/remove/modify the tables.
There is a field in the "Users" table that specify the "Role" of the user by an ID referencing an entry in the "Types" table. I want to use this field to differentiate the users by their types (which could be administrator, premium or standard for example).

Isn't it possible to assign a role to the user each time he connects?

I mean something like this in the Login.aspx.cs:

```
protected void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // On authentifie l'utilisateur via la BLL
    BusinessLogicLayer bll = new BusinessLogicLayer();

    Utilisateur user = bll.authenticate(txt_login.Text, txt_password.Text);

    // SUCCEEDED AUTH
    if (user != null)
    {
        // Ajout de l'utilisateur à son role correspondant
        if (user.Type1.nom == "lecteur")
            Roles.AddUserToRole(user.login, "lecteur");

        else if (user.Type1.nom == "journaliste")
            Roles.AddUserToRole(user.login, "journaliste");

        else if (user.Type1.nom == "administrateur")
            Roles.AddUserToRole(user.login, "administrateur");

        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user.login, cb_remember.Checked);
    }

    // FAILED AUTH (si on arrive jusqu'ici vu qu'on a pas été redirigé)
    else
        lbl_invalidCredentials.Visible = true;
}
```

I have already read the tutorial on the ASP.NET website but it uses a specific database configuration that I cannot implement.

Comment: It sounds like your "roles" mechanism isn't compatible with the ASP.NET roles provider setup.  (Yours requires each user have exactly one role, whereas usually ASP.NET allows for many-to-many users-to-roles.)  You can try to write a custom role provider, but you might not be able to fulfill the entire interface.

Comment: A custom Role provider sounds like the path of least resistance here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx

Comment: Implementing a custom role-provider seems too heavy for my basic ASP.NET website. I think I am going to go with the simpler option of not using Roles and verifying in the code-behind each page if the user is an administrator or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Role manager**  uses of the ASPDBNET.mdf (**membership**) by default.

if you want create custom role provider try this:

[How to: Sample Role-Provider Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/317sza4k.ASPX)

***Update:***
you can use Session instead of role manager:

in login page:

```
Session["role"] = "lecteur" ;
```

in admin page:

```
if(Session["role"]!=null)
{
    if(Session["role"]=="lecteur")
    { 
        //welcome admin
    }
    else
    {
        //access denied
    }
}
else
{
    //access denied
}
```

***Update***

or you can use [role provider into linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727173/how-to-role-provider-implementation-into-linq)

Comment: Implementing a custom role-provider seems too heavy for my basic ASP.NET website. I think I am going to go with the simpler option of not using Roles and verifying in the code-behind each page if the user is an administrator or not.

Comment: Ok but is it possible to restraint access from a whole directory (the admin directory) with the <authorization> tag in the Web.config file using that solution? Or will I have to implements my own verifications in the code behind of every admin page?